# GROUP BY, ORDER BY and Sub Query

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, sql-order-by

I have searched on this, but not managed to get anything working.

Not sure if this is possible, but I'll try my best to explain...

I have a couple of tables, Lodges and Scores - one to many where any lodge can have multiple scores.

```
Lodges
LodgeID (PK)
Lodge
etc

Scores
ScoreID (PK)
LodgeID (FK)
Score
Comment
```

From this, I have a list of lodges using GROUP BY lodge, showing any lodge that has any scores, and the average score for that lodge.

This all works great - however, there is also a Comment field in the Scores table, and in this list I would like to include a link to the comments if the lodge has any records in the Scores table with a comment.

I have it working, but would like the link not to display if the lodge has not received any comments. Otherwise people see the link, click on it, and there might not be any comments.

So the problem, I assume, is because using GROUP BY, it may or may not happen to show a record from the scores table that includes a comment.

I have tried using ORDER BY as well, but that just orders the results. Or using WHERE, but that only returns the lodges that have had comments. I thought HAVING might be it, but that just filtered the results again.

What I am looking for is to use GROUP BY, but for the summarised lodges (rather than all results) to be order by Comment so has if the lodge has any comments, I can use that to show or hide the link to the comments for that lodge.

I hope that makes sense, and might be possible.

Thanks.

This is my original query:

```
SELECT 
  scores.ScoreID, 
  COUNT(scores.ScoreID) as scoreCount, 
  AVG(scores.Score) as AverageScore, 
  lodges.LodgeID,   
  lodges.Lodge, 
  countries.Country, 
  lodges.CountryID, 
  categoriesFull.CategoryID, 
  nominations.NominationID, 
  scores.Comments, 
  nominations.AY_finalist, 
  nominations.AY_rank, 
  lodges.2016_Registered, 
  nominations.Year, 
  categoriesShort.CategoryShort, 
  countries.CountryShort
FROM 
  lodges 
     INNER JOIN continents 
        ON lodges.ContinentID = continents.ContinentID 
     INNER JOIN countries 
        ON lodges.CountryID = countries.CountryID 
     INNER JOIN scores 
        ON lodges.LodgeID = scores.LodgeID 
     INNER JOIN nominations 
        ON lodges.LodgeID=nominations.LodgeID 
        INNER JOIN categoriesFull 
           ON nominations.CategoriesFullID = categoriesFull.CategoryID 
          AND scores.categoryID = categoriesFull.CategoryID 
          INNER JOIN categoriesShort 
             ON categoriesFull.CategoryID = categoriesShort.CategoryShortID
WHERE 
      lodges.CountryID = 8 
  AND scores.CategoryID = 7 
  AND Year = '2016' 
  AND Nominee = 'Y' 
GROUP BY 
  Lodge
```

I have been trying sub queries, without any joy though:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
  scores.ScoreID, 
  COUNT(scores.ScoreID) as scoreCount, 
  AVG(scores.Score) as AverageScore, 
  lodges.LodgeID,   
  lodges.Lodge, 
  countries.Country, 
  lodges.CountryID, 
  categoriesFull.CategoryID, 
  nominations.NominationID, 
  scores.Comments, 
  nominations.AY_finalist, 
  nominations.AY_rank, 
  lodges.2016_Registered, 
  nominations.Year, 
  categoriesShort.CategoryShort, 
  countries.CountryShort 
FROM 
  lodges 
  INNER JOIN continents 
    ON lodges.ContinentID = continents.ContinentID 
  INNER JOIN countries 
    ON lodges.CountryID = countries.CountryID 
  INNER JOIN scores 
    ON lodges.LodgeID = scores.LodgeID 
  INNER JOIN nominations 
    ON lodges.LodgeID=nominations.LodgeID 
  INNER JOIN categoriesFull 
    ON nominations.CategoriesFullID = categoriesFull.CategoryID 
    AND scores.categoryID = categoriesFull.CategoryID 
  INNER JOIN categoriesShort 
    ON categoriesFull.CategoryID = categoriesShort.CategoryShortID
  WHERE 
  lodges.CountryID = 8 
  AND scores.CategoryID = 7 
  AND Year = '2016' 
  AND Nominee = 'Y'
ORDER BY Comments ASC)
  AS Comments 
GROUP BY 
  Lodge
```

The above just lists one lodge with ScoreCount as the total number of all scores of all the lodges in that group.

If I change the * to the fields:

```
SELECT
  scores.ScoreID, 
  COUNT(scores.ScoreID) as scoreCount, 
  AVG(scores.Score) as AverageScore, 
  lodges.LodgeID,   
  lodges.Lodge, 
  countries.Country, 
  lodges.CountryID, 
  categoriesFull.CategoryID, 
  nominations.NominationID, 
  scores.Comments, 
  nominations.AY_finalist, 
  nominations.AY_rank, 
  lodges.2016_Registered, 
  nominations.Year, 
  categoriesShort.CategoryShort, 
  countries.CountryShort 
FROM
(
SELECT 
  scores.ScoreID, 
  COUNT(scores.ScoreID) as scoreCount, 
  AVG(scores.Score) as AverageScore, 
  lodges.LodgeID,   
  lodges.Lodge, 
  countries.Country, 
  lodges.CountryID, 
  categoriesFull.CategoryID, 
  nominations.NominationID, 
  scores.Comments, 
  nominations.AY_finalist, 
  nominations.AY_rank, 
  lodges.2016_Registered, 
  nominations.Year, 
  categoriesShort.CategoryShort, 
  countries.CountryShort 
FROM 
  lodges 
  INNER JOIN continents 
    ON lodges.ContinentID = continents.ContinentID 
  INNER JOIN countries 
    ON lodges.CountryID = countries.CountryID 
  INNER JOIN scores 
    ON lodges.LodgeID = scores.LodgeID 
  INNER JOIN nominations 
    ON lodges.LodgeID=nominations.LodgeID 
  INNER JOIN categoriesFull 
    ON nominations.CategoriesFullID = categoriesFull.CategoryID 
    AND scores.categoryID = categoriesFull.CategoryID 
  INNER JOIN categoriesShort 
    ON categoriesFull.CategoryID = categoriesShort.CategoryShortID
  WHERE 
  lodges.CountryID = 8 
  AND scores.CategoryID = 7 
  AND Year = '2016' 
  AND Nominee = 'Y'
ORDER BY Comments ASC)
  AS Comments 
GROUP BY 
  Lodge
```

I get the error:

Unknown column 'scores.ScoreID' in 'field list'

Am I barking up the right tree at all?

Many thanks for any suggestions or pointers.

Comment: First, I edited your question the first query to better format the readability of the query and see the relationships to the tables.  Can you please add the proper aliases before each column such as Comments, AY_Finalist, (and rest of query).  You also have two year references in your query... why??? From same table, different table???  You SHOULD be able to just re-edit your own post to make changes there directly vs a comment here.

Comment: What do you mean "you would like the link not to display"?  What do the results look like?  What do you *want* them to look like?

Comment: Thanks - I have updated that now, with the same issues. Year shouldn't have been in there twice, just one now. Gordon - the results appear correctly, but I would like a link to a page listing all the comments if there are any for a listed lodge. If a lodge has no comments, I don't want it to appear. For that I'm just using <?php if ($row_rsLodges['Comments']<>""){ ?>LINK HERE<?php } ?>.

Comment: The issue is with the GROUP BY - the record it selects for the group could be for a lodge that does have comments, but a result which includes a record from the scores table which does not have a comment.

Comment: In the last code sample, I have tried all of scores.ScoreID, Comments.ScoreID and just ScoreID, but am getting the error that the the column is unknown for each.

Comment: Turns out all it needed was: MAX(scores.Comments) AS max_comment